# React-native [Axios Error: Network Error]

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, axios, react-native-config

I want to fetch API from my `'https://localhost:7262/api'` address, but that is giving
`Network Error`. I want to do `GET` request and then i am going to do `POST` request. Also my API server is always open during work.

What Are Your Recommendations?

```
I created this API using .Net Core 7
```

Actually, I don't know where this error is, so I felt the need to share the code blocks with you.

`Products.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, Text, FlatList, View} from 'react-native';
import ProductCard from '../../components/ProductCard/ProductCard';
import styles from '../Products/Products.style';
import getProducts from '../../fetchApi';
import useFetch from '../../fetchApi';
import Config from 'react-native-config';

const Products = () => {

  const products = useFetch(`${Config.BASE_URL}/Products`);

  const renderProduct = ({item}) => {
    <ProductCard product={item} />;
  };

  return <FlatList data={products} renderItem={renderProduct} />;
};

export default Products;
```

As you can see i want to show my all data in `FlatList` method

`ProductCard.js`

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, TouchableWithoutFeedback} from 'react-native';
import styles from './ProductCard.style';

const ProductCard = ({product}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{product.productName}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{product.quantity}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{product.category}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
};
export default ProductCard;
```

I have three pieces of data that I need to fetch and show.

`fetchApi.js`

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function useFetch(url) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  //const BASE_URL = 'https://localhost:7262/api'; //I don't use that, i use this address from .env file

  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      const {products: responseProducts} = await axios.get(url);
      setProducts(responseProducts);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);

  return {products};
}

export default useFetch;
```

This is fetchApi file, my all axios codes is here.

`.env`

```
BASE_URL = https://localhost:7262/api/
```

I get URL from environment file as you can see, if you have other solution you can tell me and i can change that.

`Package.json`

```
{
  "name": "apidotnet",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "ios-dev": "react-native run-ios --scheme \"apidotnetDev\"",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.10",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-config": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.13",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.2",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "jest": "^29.4.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.75.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

`Router.js`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import Products from './pages/Products';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Router = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="ProductsPage"
          component={Products}
          options={{
            title: 'Ürünler',
            headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'green'},
            headerTitleStyle: {color: 'white'},
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
export default Router;
```

`.Net File`

```
using System;
using InventoryControl.Models;
using InventoryControl.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace InventoryControl.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ProductsService _productsService;
        public ProductsController(ProductsService productsService) =>
            _productsService = productsService;
        

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<List<Products>> Get() => await _productsService.GetProductAsync();

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task <IActionResult> Post(Products newProduct)
        {
            await _productsService.CreateProductAsync(newProduct);
            

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Get), new { id = newProduct.Id }, newProduct);
        }


        [HttpGet("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Products>> Get(string id)
        {
            var product = await _productsService.GetProductAsync(id);

            if(product is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return product;
        }
        [HttpPut("{id:length(24)}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Update(string id, Products updatedProduct)
        {
            var product = await _productsService.GetProductAsync(id);//first step, we must fetch the data from id

            if(product is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            updatedProduct.Id = product.Id;

            await _productsService.UpdateProductAsync(id, updatedProduct);
            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
        {
            var product = await _productsService.GetProductAsync(id);
            if(product is null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            await _productsService.RemoveProductAsync(id);

            return NoContent();
        }


        
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you already tested your api and its working fine on that end right?

Comment: Yes exactly, it works on Postman and Swagger. I can post or get any data using that api.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is two problems with your `BASE_URL` env variable.

1. Remove the `s` of `http`. `localhost` is most of the time unsecure
2. Remove the last `/`

```
BASE_URL=http://localhost:7262/api
```

**EDIT:**

Could try to edit your `useFetch` hook and share the log to us:

```js
function useFetch(url) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const getProducts = async () => {
    try {
      axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(request, null, 2)); // <--- this log
        return request;
      });
      
      const {products: responseProducts} = await axios.get(url);
      setProducts(responseProducts);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getProducts();
  }, []);
```

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: I did and it gave `Network Error` again.

Comment: Can you remove the last `/` in your `BASE_URI` env?

Comment: I already did that.

Comment: Can you double check and restart your server. If you don't, new env variables won't get live updated

Comment: Is my fetchApi file correct?

Comment: Yes it is. It could be improved (but this is an other question). Can you try to replace your `axios.get` line with: `const {products: responseProducts} = await axios.get("http://localhost:7262/api/Products");` ?

Comment: I got same error when i changed. I think i cannot get URL correctly, am i right?

Comment: Because i use a config and .env file, maybe we change that method, i mean can we use another method instead of config and .env file?

Comment: can you share the route file as well ?

Comment: I already shared.

Comment: The `.Net` file

Comment: Did you fixed the issue ?

Comment: No i couldn't fix that. and also i added .net file on the questions, you can see on the up.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Can you update your question with the `request` log?

Comment: When ı added `url: string`, it gives `Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files.` error

Comment: oups. I have updated it

Comment: it doesn't work. I guess i found the main problem, it would be `localhost` . Because you said fetchApi file is correct, so my code parts cannot wrong. It can be another thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing on iOS, make sure you added the desired URL in the [App Transport Security settings](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=jxky8h89). Then, run `npx react-native run-ios`.

Comment: It didn't work.